# SAS date imported wrong

Tags: sas

When I imported my excel sheet some dates imported differently than others. I tried to fix this with the code below to format the date.

```
DATA volume;
SET mice.volume;
format Date MMDDYY10.;
run;
```

However, I received the following error.

ERROR 48-59: The format $MMDDYY was not found or could not be loaded.

I had also tried with the following code

```
DATA volume;
SET mice.volume;
If date= 44138 then date= '11/3';
If date= 44141 then date= '11/6';
run;
```

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).

A Proc Contents shows the variable= Date type= Char Len=7 format=$7 Informat=$7 Label= Date

How do I fix this?

[image: Snap of some of the data]

Comment: It will be easier to fix the Excel file first. Make sure the column with the dates only has dates in very cell or only strings in every cell. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872050/importing-dates-from-excel-to-sas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date column being character having a mix of 'date looking' strings, and Excel date value numbers tells me some of the date values in your Excel are actually strings, such as `'11/10` or `='11/10'`.

The raw number `44138` is:

- a SAS date value is `04-NOV-2080` (obviously not what is wanted)
- an Excel date value `03-NOV-2020` (aha!)
- `03-NOV-2020` as SAS date value is `22222`

  - an offset of `-21916` from Excel
- `-21916` is the SAS date `30-DEC-1899`

**Date Epochs**

An epoch is the date corresponding to a base number `0` in a systems calendar.  
*SAS Base year is `1960` and Excel Base year is `1900`.*

```
                     Formatted 
Number  Actual Date  Date Shown   System/Format
------  -----------  -----------  ----------
     0  31-DEC-1899  1/0/1900     Excel / Short Date (Formatter is weird at Epoch)
     0  01-JAN-1960  01-JAN-1960  SAS / DATE11.
 21916  01-JAN-1960  1/1/1960     Excel / Short Date
-21916  30-DEC-1899  31-DEC-1899  SAS / DATE11.
```

Notice the *round trip* is from `31-dec-1899` to `30-dec-1899`.  This due to an Excel 97 bug that has been carried forth for legacy reasons.  See Microsoft's explanation in ["Excel incorrectly assumes that the year 1900 is a leap year"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/wrongly-assumes-1900-is-leap-year) which pushes the blame back even further to Lotus 1-2-3

The formula to convert between systems S1 and S2 date numbers is to add the # for the other systems epoch date (@ # 0)

```
SAS#(date) = Excel#(date) + SAS#(Excel Epoch Date) - 1 (Excel leap year bug), or
sas_dt = excel_dt + '31-DEC-1899'd - 1; *or;
sas_dt = excel_dt + '30-DEC-1899'd;
```

**What happened**

Mixed value types in the Excel `date` column forced `IMPORT` to perceive the `date` variable as character.

- The Excel cells with a date looking ***m/d*** string were brought in as the string
- The Excel cells with a date, likely custom formatted as ***m/d***, were brought in as the underlying Excel date number.

**The ERROR**

You tried to apply the date format `MMDDYY.` to the character variable `Date`.
A character column can not be assigned a numeric or date format, thus you get the

```
ERROR 48-59: The format $MMDDYY was not found or could not be loaded.
```

SAS automatically presumed `MMDDYY.` meant a character format `$MMDDYY.` because the variable type was character.

**The Fix**

You can convert the values in the character `date` column with code such as the following (untested):

```
  if index(date,'/') then 
    date_fixed = input (trim(date)||'/2020', mmddyy10.);
  else 
    date_fixed = input(date,best12.) + '30-DEC-1899'D;

  format date_fixed yymmdd10.;
```

If you want to continue showing **only** mm/dd in SAS, use the format `NLDATEM5.`

```
  format date_fixed NLDATEM5.;
```

Comment: Excel dates are normally based from 1900 (but might be using 1904) but SAS uses 1960.  To fix add the date value '30DEC1899'd , which is a negative number.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, cleaned up the answer a lot.

Comment: You need to use 30DEC1899 because Excel treats 1900 as a leap year.