# SAS Extract date from CSV import and and then Extract Month

Tags: csv, sas

I have imported a csv in SAS Enterprise Guide with a value in the Date column of 44165. This is the value for 30th November 2020 in Excel ? How do I get SAS to extract the month as "Nov" from this value? Do I have to convert this numeric value to a date first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SAS will not normally do that with a CSV file that is properly formatted.  If you look at the CSV file with a text editor does it literally have the string `44165` in it or does it show the value using some other characters? If so then how did you create the CSV file from the Excel file. Note that CSV files are just text files and NOT Excel files, even if your computer defaults to using Excel to open them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64979048/sas-date-imported-wrong/64980189#64980189

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me with this @Tom .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might, it depends on what the import process did.  If `date` is numeric, the variable can be formatted.

```
format date monname3.;
```

If `date` is a character variable there are likely some rows in the CSV with weird, missing, or a mix of date value text and other `date` values (maybe some one entered `n/a` or `???` in the original data source that was exported as CSV.)

Use `input` to convert a character value containing digit characters to a number.

```
xls_epoch = '31DEC1899'D;
sas_date = input (xls_date,5.) + xls_epoch;

format sas_date monname.;
drop xls_date xls_epoch;
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard ! That has resolved my query!

Comment: Just converting the string to a number will not work right if the digit strings have values like `44165`.  You also need to add the negative number `'30DEC1899'd` to adjust for different basis dates.

Comment: Good point @Tom.  How ever, uncorrected dates formatted as `MONNAME3.` will be viewed as 'correct' (the month name shown) most of the time despite the date being off by the source calendar epoch.

Comment: Your XLS_EPOCH value is off by 1 day. Excel treats 1900 has a leap year.